# Retornar uma mensagem de "erro" caso a consulta ao mysql retorne vazio

Tags: php, mysql, null, empty

Galera estou começando agora em PHP, e queria uma ajudinha, preciso que uma página retorne uma mensagem dizendo que o banco está vazio, mas não estou conseguindo, eis meu código:

```
</head>
<body>
     <table class="form-control" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Nome</td>
                <td>E-mail</td>
                <td>Data de criação</td>
                <td>Idade</td>
                <td>Cidade</td>
                <td>CPF</td>
                <td>Menssagem</td>
            </tr>
            <?php while($dado = $resultado_usuario->fetch_array()){  ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $dado["id"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dado["nome"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dado["email"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime($dado["created"])); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dado["idade"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dado["cidade"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dado["cpf"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dado["mensagem"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table><br>
    <input type="submit" name="" class="sub2" value="Voltar" onclick="location. href='siteform.html'">
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar um verificar a quantidade de linhas retornadas, caso seja maior que 0, ele faz o `while()` caso contrario ele pode exibir um `echo()` com uma mensagem de erro

Ficaria assim:

```
</head>
<body>
     <table class="form-control" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Nome</td>
                <td>E-mail</td>
                <td>Data de criação</td>
                <td>Idade</td>
                <td>Cidade</td>
                <td>CPF</td>
                <td>Menssagem</td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            if($resultado_usuario->num_rows() > 0) { 
            while($dado = $resultado_usuario->fetch_array()){  ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $dado["id"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dado["nome"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dado["email"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime($dado["created"])); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dado["idade"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dado["cidade"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dado["cpf"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dado["mensagem"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } 
            }else{
              echo "Não foi encontrado nada";
            }
            ?>
        </table><br>
    <input type="submit" name="" class="sub2" value="Voltar" onclick="location. href='siteform.html'">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($resultado_usuario->num_rows() > 0) { 

while($dado = $resultado_usuario->fetch_array()) {  
//Conteúdo se não for vazio
      }
}
else {
//Retorno vazio 
}
```